# Consider the table and create 3d array in python using numpy

Tags: pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have this table, and using this I need to create a 3D array in python using numpy. I can't figure out how this 3d array is layed out, can anyone help?

```
time    field 1  field 2
1       0.25     1
2       0.1      1.1
3       0.6      1.3
4       0.87     0.9
5       0.4      0.7
6       0.6      1
7       0.5      0.6
8       0.12     0.8
9       0.4      1.1
```

Comment: Wait! Where is the third dimention in the dataset you have provided? It is just a matrix of values. What do you want the third dimension to be?

Comment: I don't know, this is what our lecturer gave us but didn't explain it. That's what i got confused about because is it not a 2d array otherwise?

Comment: Well then, I think you should consider asking your lecturer/professor to provide data for the third dimension unless the dataset has been provided in the context of the lecture. Otherwise, I don't see how would one answer this question.

Comment: Another small  question, how would you perform binning on that 2d array?